# Everything working fine but i changed in route file to add the prefix .It started showing reflection exception that controller does not exist

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, lumen

```
$app->post('api/register', 'UserController@store');
```

Here everything working fine.function is `aceesible via route/api/register`,but when i changed this to add prefix

```
$app->group(['prefix' => 'api'], function ($app) {

$app->post('register', 'UserController@store');

});
```

This shows me

> reflection exception that class UserController does not exist. Lumen
>   5.1 php 7 apache 2.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you did not change the file position as well, probably it's a namespace issue.

Comment: no i did'nt change anything just in route as description given in question

Answer (score 1):

If you use `group` method, make sure you identify the namespace of that group:

```
$app->group(['prefix' => 'api', 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function ($app) {
    $app->post('register', 'UserController@store');
});
```

It would solve your problem.

Comment: @PankajCheema Upvote it and approve it would be nice :)

Comment: I have upvoted but my reputation is below 15 that's why it is not visible  .But thanks from my heart !!!

Comment: @PankajCheema Aaah, it's okay. no problem :)